# sendmail using "<" fails but using "|" works, why?

Tags: email, unix, sendmail

Newbie question: I have a simple script that builds a text file with the sendmail headers, required blank line and then text body. When I run:
`sendmail -t < email.txt`
it fails with a "No recipient addresses found in header" error.
However, when I run:
`cat email.txt | sendmail -t`
it works and the recipients receive my email.

I'm just wondering why it is behaving this way.
I'm on an AIX 6100-09-12-1846 (oslevel -s) box.
I just tested on a Linux box and it worked both ways, so I can only assume that AIX handles it differently, but I don't know why.

Update:
The following contents are in "email.txt"

```
Subject: Test Email
To: foo@bar.com
From: Mail.Relay@bar.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 </HEAD>
 <BODY lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple>
    <FONT SIZE=8>
    This is a test email.<BR/>
    </FONT>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

But only when using "|" into sendmail does it work, not when redirected using "<". I'm confused.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
racer

Comment: It does work for me on AIX6.1 (both formats). Please provide more details.

Comment: It may be caused by strange "end of line" sequences.  Make `To:` header first and inspect received message if it works.

Comment: Try this command: `od -tx1 < email.txt >test1.txt; cat email.txt | od -tx1 >test2.txt; cmp test1.txt test2.txt`. If it doesn't show difference, then it is dark magic.

Comment: There's no difference... I suppose it is dark magic then. Really strange! What is especially weird is that I have another environment that is the same AIX version and when I run a similar test there both methods work!?! I guess I'll just chalk this up to dark magic as you say.

Comment: Well there is also truss(1) but that's not for beginners. `truss sendmail -t < email.txt 2>truss1.log; cat email.txt | truss sendmail -t 2>truss2.log` Comparing the two logfile _might_ give some hint.